# Adding actor to ClutterCanvas

Tags: canvas, actor, cairo, clutter

I have a `ClutterCanvas` which has a white background painted by an initial `draw` signal. I want to add an actor to this canvas. The actor would be a point.

```
void drawPoint(ClutterCanvas *canvas, cairo_t *cr, double x, double y, double r){
ClutterColor color;
color = *CLUTTER_COLOR_Black;
clutter_cairo_set_source_color(cr, &color);
cairo_arc(cr, x, y, r, 0, 2 * M_PI);
cairo_fill(cr);
}
```

How to add this point as an actor to the canvas?

Point may be created as an actor using:

```
point = clutter_actor_new();
clutter_actor_set_content(point, ??);
clutter_actor_add_child(stage, point);
```

Will this approach lead me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the `ClutterCanvas` class is for direct drawing with Cairo — it's similar to the `<canvas>` tag on HTML.

you can only add child actors to existing `ClutterActor` instances.

child actors will be drawn through their parent when painting the content of the scene graph. child actors can also have their own `ClutterContent` implementation; if you want to use a `ClutterCanvas` and don't want to cover the contents of their parent, make sure to clear the content of the `ClutterCanvas` with a transparent color.

Comment: So if I use `ClutterCanvas` then I can add the actors with their own `ClutterCanvas` and stack them up? Then how can I select the actor that is one layer below or say at the bottom of that stack, for some other operations? Will that be tough or there is already some mechanism in-place for that?

Comment: what does "select the actor" mean? you have an entire API for iterating through the scene graph, from the top-level parent (the stage) through its children, and vice versa.